# How much data does Hearthstone Mobile App use?

Tags: hearthstone

I've just started to play Hearthstone and I'm going to play it on my mobile phone while traveling.

I wonder how much data does the mobile app use on average for an online game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to DisguisedToast's testing a year ago, an average game of Hearthstone takes about 150kb of data.

[image: Disguised Toast's infographic]

Comment thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/32pgus/hearthstone_on_phones_data_usage_battery_drain/?st=isnec4pg&sh=b7259aa6

Comment: Jeez up to 10% battery loss per game. Nice that it's so low on data though.

Comment: @BritishFerret 10% may seem like a lot, but I'll take the battery usage of Hearthstone over Pokemon Go any day

Comment: I don't know anything about Hearthstone - what do they mean by control warrior vs control warrior? Is this a joke or an actual mode that might consume ridiculous amounts of data?

Comment: @Random832, It's a joke.  A control vs control match up can last a very long time because both sides are waiting for the other side to make their move.  In the case of warrior they just build up armor during this waiting period which makes the game last even longer.

Comment: Control vs control got me laughing.

Answer (score 3):

Data usage seems relatively low, but in my experience the battery drain become an issue very quickly. Would recommend an external battery or staying plugged in if possible.